# BIM 360 Compare documents

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360

is there any way to revive data about what has been changed between versions (remove and add and modify):
[image]
via [forge Model Derivative API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/), now I am able to get all the metadata of any Revit files but in total so I am not sure what elements added or .....
the problem we have a lot of files, and it's really hard to run a test to compare modes for each object

thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of any built-in BIM360 or Forge functionaloity for obtaining that information.

I would suggest that you very clearly define exactly what information you wish to keep track of and determine how that can be obtained from a model, e.g., as you suggest, via the Forge Model Derivative API.

Then, you can create a snapshot of that data yourself and implement the functionality to track changes in it as you wish.

The Buiilding Coder discusses and shows how to solve the exact same task for Revit BIMs using the Revit API on the Windows desktop:

- [Tracking Element Modification](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/01/tracking-element-modification.html)
- [Implementing the TrackChangesCloud External Event](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/03/implementing-the-trackchangescloud-external-event.html)

Those articles provide ideas and guidelines on some aspects to take into consideration addressing the same task in Forge.